CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available
I need to use bitsandbytes package to run a code which uses Falcon7B model. I have installed CUDA and my system has a NVIDIA RTX A6000 GPU. My system has Windows 11 OS.
Here is the code, it is just the importing section:
import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, TrainingArguments, GenerationConfig
from peft import LoraConfig, get_peft_model, PeftConfig, PeftModel, prepare_model_for_kbit_training
from trl import SFTTrainer
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

Here is the error:
RuntimeError: 
        CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available. Please run the following command to get more information:

        python -m bitsandbytes

        Inspect the output of the command and see if you can locate CUDA libraries. You might need to add them
        to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you suspect a bug, please take the information from python -m bitsandbytes
        and open an issue at: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues



RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.training_args because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):

        CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available. Please run the following command to get more information:

        python -m bitsandbytes

        Inspect the output of the command and see if you can locate CUDA libraries. You might need to add them
        to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you suspect a bug, please take the information from python -m bitsandbytes
        and open an issue at: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues

This error sometimes doesn't appear and the code works. But most of the times I get this error and I am unable to find an accurate fix.
This error first appeared when CUDA wasn't installed in the system. It didn't give an error after installation, but when I ran it again the next day, the same error appeared.
Next I tried downgrading python version to below 3.11.1, the code ran again after that. But again today I am facing the same error.
Here is my CUDA version:
nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Feb__8_05:53:42_Coordinated_Universal_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0


Can't say I fully understand how it eventually worked (I was tired after many hours of trying different things) but I followed https://huggingface.co/docs/bitsandbytes/main/en/installation#cuda-pip guidelines along with the install.sh script with correct CUDA_VERSION and a compatible GPU.
